# How to increase the speed of rendering

Tags: rendering

What is the effect of increasing your ram in blender?  Especially in the speed of rendering

Answer (score 4):

RAM is mostly about storage amount. More ram will allow you to render more complex & more populated scenes (more objects, more polygons, more textures, etc....).

It will not have a significative impact on render times, unless you have less ram than is needed to handle the *complexity* of your scene (the more complex the scene the more ram is required) - in which case your system will store on your hard drives, which are way slower.

The important hardwares in render times are the CPU and the GPU.